# Call a static method given it's dynamic type and arguments in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with a static method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static bool MyMethod<T>(string arg1) where T : class {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I invoke that given that I know my type for `T` should be `MyNamespace.Data.Models.Student` (which is provided via a variable), and the value for `arg1` is let's say `student`.

Is it similar to the following? I'm not sure how to set the `T` type for it tho.

```
Type.GetType("MyClass").GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(null, new object[] { arg1 = "student" })
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `MakeGenericMethod` method of `MethodInfo`:

```
Type.GetType("MyClass")
    .GetMethod("MyMethod")
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeOfGenericArgument)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { "student" })
```

Answer (score 3):

First you should get your method and use [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
 var methodType =Type.GetType("MyClass").GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.Static |BindingFlags.Public);
 var argumentType = typeof (Student);
 var method = methodType.MakeGenericMethod(argumentType);
 method.Invoke(null, new object[] { "student" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `BindingFlags.Static` in `GetMethod` to get a static method.  Once you've done that, you can make a generic method via [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to construct the method with the proper type.

Comment: Unless there is a similarly named instance method making it ambiguous, the `Static` flag isn't needed.